# Cast all columns in bigquery to float/string

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm trying to download a BQ table using python like this:
from google.cloud import bigquery

```
client = bigquery.Client()
SQL_QUERY = """
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
"""
df = client.query(SQL_QUERY).to_dataframe()
```

I get the following error in the traceback. Looks like, the [google-cloud-sdk](https://gcloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/cloud/bigquery/_helpers.html) first converts the table to a JSON format and them dumps to a CSV.

```
    converter = _CELLDATA_FROM_JSON[field.field_type]
KeyError: 'NUMERIC'
```

I've two questions:

1. Is there a way to cast all columns in a BQ to float/string before downloading it using Python?
2. How do I identify which columns are causing the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

If you distinctively mention your column names, your queries can become more readable.

Lets say your table has 3 columns (`a`, `b` and `c`). If you want to cast these as floats, you can simply modify your query to:

```
SQL_QUERY = """
  SELECT 
    cast(a as float64) as a, 
    cast(b as float64) as b, 
    cast(c as float64) as c
  FROM TABLE
"""
```

Comment: I am aware that I can do that. I was wondering if there is a way to identify the data type of each column?